# variable in curl call within bash script does not work

Tags: bash, shell, variables, curl, cloudflare

When I'm running echo $ROUTE_ID (this is an extracted value from a JSON file), it gives the correct output.

But when I'm using $ROUTE_ID in the below curl command it does not assign the ROUTE_ID value.

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/%env.ZONE_ID_AU%/workers/routes/$ROUTE_ID}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer %env.APITOKEN_ClOUDFLARE%" --data-raw ''
```

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you have a rogue `}` after `$ROUTE_ID`